# Every group of order $35$ is cyclic?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, cyclic-groups

Prove that every group of order $35$ is cyclic.

---

Now, the subgroups of this are ones whose orders divide the order of this group(by lagrange), these are of prime orders $7$ and $5$.

and I guess $\Bbb Z_7\times \Bbb Z_5$ is of order $35$ and since these are both cyclic, so is $\Bbb Z_{35}$.

But that doesn't prove anything about **every** subgroup of order $35$.

How do I do this.

Comment: Have you learned the Sylow theorems?

Comment: @MarcusM I haven't, but I can.

Comment: Okay, it's fairly straightforward with the Sylow theorems, but there might be a way to do the problem without it.  There are a lot of theorems to help you out in this problem; another (slightly more obscure) theorem that would apply here is that for every group of order $n$, if $n$ and $\varphi(n)$ are coprime, then the group is cyclic.  Here we have $n = 35$, $\varphi(n) = (7 - 1)(5 - 1) = 24$.  Since these two numbers are coprime, the group is cyclic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The number of 7 Sylow subgroups divides 5 and is congruent to 1 mod $7$, hence there's a unique one, and hence normal. Similarly, the number of $5$ Sylow subgroups divides 7 and is congruent to $1$ mod $5$, hence there's a unique one. It follows that $G \cong \mathbb{Z}/7\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}\cong \mathbb{Z}/35\mathbb{Z}$ by Chinese remainder theorem.